# TSLint for Angular JS - Setting, Configuration and implementation

Tags: angularjs, tslint

I am using AngularJs project and the requirement is to use tslint to **treat warnings as errors**.

I have went through the palantir website (https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/cli/)
and follow all the steps to install the tslint like below:

`npm install tslint typescript --save-dev`

`-i, --init:` - Generates a tslint.json config file in the current working directory.

I can see the tslint.json file in my project directory, now I am stuck here.The rules are not reflecting, not sure if I am doing correct things to run tslint on project files.

I need little guidance here to understand:

1. How to run tslint to check if rules are running perfectly.
2. Is it automatically runs in background or is there any command to run tslilnt rules?
3. How can I set rule to **treat warnings as errors** for all the js files in the project?

Can anyone explains the steps to follow to implement tslint in AngularJS project using VSCode, please?

I am using **Visual Studio Code** to develop the application.

My tslint.json looks like below:

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "complierOptions":{

        "allowJs":true
    },
    "jsRules": {
        "no-invalid-this": false,
        "severity": "error",
        "max-line-length": {
            "options": [120]
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "severity": "error" 

    },
    "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

I have alrady try to refer some of the links but no luck.

one of then is -[TSLint configuration for Angular 1 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605229/tslint-configuration-for-angular-1-project)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin) on vscode?

`npm install tslint typescript --save-dev` only install the functionality to run tslint from the terminal, it's useful as a pre-commit hook for example.

Try `tslint --fix -p .`in your terminal to use it.

Comment: Yes, we do have extension in vscode. What command I can use to show warnings as errors?

"tslint --fix -p" This command will directly fix all the warnings or it'll show first and then fix?

Comment: For me, I don't need to install tslint via npm to use it in vscode, just install the addons show me the errors, and there are no extension setting for this addons. With `--fix`, tslint will try to fix minor mistakes and show you only the more complex, like shadowed name, `-p` is for use a certain path.

Comment: Ok. Cool. I'll check with addons then. Thanks